# jQuery prevent other events after a click while function in progress

Tags: jquery

I have two links `a` with classes `.next-button-1` and `.prev-button-1` and when I click on the buttons is calls different functions

```
    $('.next-button-1').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    gotoNext();
});

$('.prev-button-1').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    gotoPrev();
});
```

The performing of each function takes some time. Is there any way to make the button could not click until the function is executed?

**upd**
I have found the solution:

```
$('.next-button-1').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    if ($(this).hasClass('disabled'))
        return false; 
     else {
        $(this).addClass('disabled');
        gotoNext();
    }
});

$('.prev-button-1').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    if ($(this).hasClass('disabled'))
        return false; 
     else {
        $(this).addClass('disabled');
        gotoPrev();
    }
});
```

and I remove class  `'disabled'`
`$('.next-button-1').removeClass('disabled');` in `gotoNext()` function
and
`$('.prev-button-1').removeClass('disabled');` in `gotoPrev()` function

Comment: are they button elements or span or any other element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```js
$('.next-button-1').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).prop('disabled', true);
    gotoNext();
});

$('.prev-button-1').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).prop('disabled', true);
    gotoPrev();
});
```

Then re-enable it with `$(your selector for the button).prop('disabled', false);` at the end of the function which take some time to execute.

**Edit:**

As your buttons are `a` tags this solution won't work. Instead you can unbind and rebind your events handlers like this:

```js
function nextHandler(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).unbind("click", nextHandler);
    gotoNext();
}

function prevHandler(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).unbind("click", prevHandler);
    gotoPrev();
}

$('.next-button-1').click(nextHandler);
$('.prev-button-1').click(prevHandler);
```

Then re-enable them with `$('.next-button-1').click(nextHandler);` at the end of your slow function. For clarity and uniformity you might want to use `$.bind("click", handler)` instead of `$.click(handler)`.

More information about `.bind()/.unbind()` [here.](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/)

**Better solution:**

```js
function nextHandler(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    gotoNext();
}

function prevHandler(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    gotoPrev();
}

$('.next-button-1').one('click', nextHandler);
$('.prev-button-1').one('click', prevHandler);
```

Then at the end of your slow function add this: `$('.next-button-1').one('click', nextHandler);` (same form prev of course).

More information about `.one()` [here.](http://api.jquery.com/one/)

Comment: I use links `a`, not buttons. Can I use ur code in this case?

Comment: Nop, sorry. I'll check if they are some workaround for the `a` tag.

Comment: Not a problem) I have found the solution and added it in my question.

Comment: Good. The only other solution I see is to unbind your events listeners then re-bind them after. It may be shorter than the class solution.

Comment: Can u explain me about it?